# Pick file names stored in an Array and attach those files over email VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, office-automation

I am trying to pick files with names stored in a cell with comma separated and attached those files over email. Below is the code which I am working on and I keep on getting RunTime error 438.

I am struggling to figure out what is going wrong, your expertise would help me to resolve the issue

```
Private Sub test3()
    Dim mess_body As String, StrFile As String, StrPath As String
    Dim appOutLook As Object
    Dim MailOutLook As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Elem As Variant
    Dim myArr As Variant

    
    
    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    StrPath = Sheets("Input").Range("E3").Value
    
    With MailOutLook
        .To = "manoj.sahoo@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "test"
        .HTMLBody = "test"
        
        
        With Worksheets("DL")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        myArr = Split(.Range("B" & i).Value, ",")
     

       
        For Each Elem In myArr
               
           StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "\" & Elem & ".xlsx")
'
            Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
            

            .attachments.Add StrPath & "\" & StrFile
            StrFile = Dir
        Loop
        
        Next Elem

    Next i
End With

'
        .Display
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you a) would indent your code properly  b) Tell us which line throws that error and what the error message is. As 438 is "Object does not support this property or method", it could help to switch to early binding and let the compiler show you the problem.

Comment: Below is the line where it is gets stuck

.attachments.Add StrPath & "\" & StrFile

Comment: According to your code `.attachments.Add` refers the last used `With`. I mean, `Worksheets("DL")`, which does not have an 'attachments` property. So, firstly try `MailOutLook.attachments.Add` and see if other issues appear... are there parts of the workbooks name and that's why you use `StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "\" & Elem & ".xlsx")`?

Comment: works perfectly now, thank you.  yes for StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "\" & Elem & ".xlsx")

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested `With` operators in the code:

```
  With MailOutLook
        .To = "manoj.sahoo@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "test"
        .HTMLBody = "test"
        
        
        With Worksheets("DL")
```

The `Worksheet` doesn't have the `Attachments` property. You need to explicitly use the source object in the nested `With` operator.

```
MailOutLook.attachments.Add StrPath & "\" & StrFile
```

Finally, make sure that you pass a valid file path to the `Add` method of the `Attachments` class. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.